# if user input length = x , btn.click() function

Tags: javascript

little question, 
I'm trying to automaticly run the function when the input field is 7 characters long.

I've tried some different snippets :

```
var barcodeMeting = document.getElementById("barcode").value.length;

 if(barcodeMeting.innerHTML.length == 7)
{
    document.getElementById('btn').click();
}
```

and

```
if(docement.getElementById('barcode').length == 7)
{
    document.getElementById('btn').click();
}
```

and

```
count = barcodeParsing.length ;
     if(count >= 6)
{
    document.getElementById('btn').click();
}
```

Anyone who knows an easy solution?

my function with ajax post looks like :

```
$("#btn").click(function(){...}
```

and my input field :

```
                <input type="text" name="barcode" id="barcode" class="inputBarcode" placeholder="  Wachten op barcode scan..">
```

Comment: You need to listen for keypress events.... Those if statements do not magically keep running. FYI one equal `=` is assignment

Comment: you need to re-align the codes it looks really messy now..

Comment: If you want to automatically submit, you should `.submit()` the form instead of `.click()` a button

Answer (score 1):

The solution below uses a keyup and sets the maxlength on the input to 7 to simplify UI handling. Once the desired length is met, then it submits the containing form.

Sample JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmvmLqaa/4/

Updated input with maxlength set to 7:

```
<input type="text" name="barcode" id="barcode" class="inputBarcode" placeholder="  Wachten op barcode scan.." maxlength="7"/>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#barcode').keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.length > 6) {
            $(this.form).submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just use `$(this.form).submit()` instead of that `.closest("form")`-like thingy

Comment: Also you might want to switch to the simpler `this.value.length`, and you should use `>6` so that it can't even be fooled by pasting etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of watching on the click event, you need to watch on keypress, or keyup events.

Also, you do not have a btn ID in your code. The ID of your input is 'barcode'.

Try something like...

```
$('#barcode').on('keypress', function(){
    // function to run
});
```

Comment: Thanks in advantance. I need to check the length. maybe a counter would work? On the 7th character the button needs to click. made a var for the length of a barcode.

Comment: Yes, you would check the length as part of the function that runs in the keypress check.